# Trouble killing logcat process

Tags: root-access, termux, processes

On my rooted Android, I have a screenshot from Termux after running `sudo htop`. There is a logcat process running with PID 925. I want to stop this process.

[image]

So far, I've tried running `su -c kill 925` which is the Process ID of the logcat process I'm trying to stop but have been unsuccessful.

How to stop this process?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to stop the logcat service and kill the process by issuing the following command:

```
sudo setprop logd.logpersistd stop && sudo kill 925
```

Comment: Hello. How did you figure out about `logd.logpersistd` property? Knowing the answer is good. Knowing "the way" that lead to the answer is even better.

Comment: "How did you figure out about logd.logpersistd"      It's not supposed to be a secret but what I did was ask the question somewhere else.

Comment: Then you should have attributed the answer to whomever provided this answer to you elsewhere. This answer is written  as if you came up with the solution originally.